# i want to include a header blade in my template but i keep getting a 'undefined variable $slot'

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently facing an issue while working with Blade templates in Laravel. I have successfully created a template file and extended it for different pages. However, when I try to include the header and footer in the child Blade templates, I encounter the error message 'Undefined variable $slot'.

I have set up the template file with @yield() to define the sections, and in the specific Blade templates, I use @section() to fill in the content for the corresponding sections.

Here are the methods I've attempted to include the header in the child Blade templates:

1. Using @include('header')
2. Trying @component('header') @endcomponent

Unfortunately, both methods result in the same 'Undefined variable $slot' error, and my header is not displayed.

How can I properly include the header in the child Blade templates without encountering the 'Undefined variable $slot' error and ensure it gets displayed as expected? Any insights or solutions to this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You include header and footer in child components, not in layout?

Comment: @Maksim i tried both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the following in your main file

```
<HTML>
<head></head>
<body>
@yield('section')
</body>
</html>
```

in your other file

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('section')
    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@endsection
```

You can read more at https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#extending-a-layout

Comment: I already use this. My question is how can i insert a blade in the section without getting my error

Comment: But why you need to include header. just create a main file with header and footer and yield all components which you need dynamic.

Comment: for better readability. When i want to edit the header structure later on, i just want to edit the 'header.blade' file.

Comment: ```@include('header')``` does this is inside same folder where the file exist ?

Comment: yes, its in the same folder.

Comment: somehow adding a part of the path in the @include('.../header') solved the problem. Thank you for your service